# Are store perks cumulative? Do you need lower levels?

Tags: dungeon-hearts

Store have several perks with different ranks: for example **Venom 1** that gives 2% chance of poison on archer attack and **Venom 3** that gives 10% chance.

I've noticed that I can collect XP and directly buy **Venom 3** without buying lower ranks.

Do I need lower ranks for anything? Are they giving any cumulative bonuses if I have higher ranks or can I ignore them and go directly for highest rank instead?